# remove .php extension from filename containing dashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

For removing .php extension form URL with filename containing dashes like

```
http://www.sitename.com/here-the-filename-with-dashes.php
http://www.sitename.com/filename.php
to
http://www.sitename.com/here-the-filename-with-dashes
http://www.sitename.com/filename
```

I have tried several number of code already but no use via htaccess file. 
Here HTACCESS FILE:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$http://www.sitename.ca/?$1.php [L,R=302]
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.sitename.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sitename.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.sitename.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [QSA,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Oh! That's perfect...(y) Thank you

Comment: This showing **http://www.sitename.com/about?history** for **about.php?history** and redirect to **404 page**. How can I rewrite url **http://www.sitename.com/about/history** and redirect page to the same **about page** with query string **history**.

Comment: @tffaku What have you tried to that effect? Redirection of URLs is quite easy to achieve. For reference, you can use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a `RewriteCond` directive to achieve tht.

Comment: For replacing **question mark** by **slash**, should I replace last rule **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]** to **RewriteRule ^([^./]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L]**?

Comment: Or **RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2 [L,QSA]**?